# Correct way to set different auth header based on request url in angular interceptor?

Tags: angular

I have 2 api's which have different starting url's and both take different headers. So I want to set headers based on specific url request. 
At the moment both if conditions are always true even if its a component that doesn't make a request to 122.22.332.3/anylink
Where should I put the `return next.handle(req);` because if I put it in the first if then second if wont run.

```
 export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
      intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler,
      ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.url.indexOf('/maxim/public') === -1) {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
          }
        });

      }
      if (req.url.indexOf('122.22.332.3/') === -1) {
        console.log("x");
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer dsfdsfdsfdsfsdxcsdfw23dsfdsf`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(req);
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are the different APIs called from the same module? If so, how hard would it be to split the module?

Comment: there is one module app module in my project

Comment: Also, you're using indexOf, and checking against -1, so both conditions can evaluate to true if neither indeOf finds a match. So, if it's not 122.22.332.3/, the second will always run, if it's not /maxim/public, the first will always run, if neither, they both will run.

Comment: Does there only being one module mean you cannot have multiple? There are a lot of unknowns that make it difficult to give good input.

Comment: I want to have one module atm.. the some api's are used to login and register others to fetch data and do certain things.

Comment: First, fix your conditionals (flip them: instead of checking for -1 check for > -1) so only if they're found they run instead if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment both if conditions are always true even if its a
>   component that doesn't make a request to 122.22.332.3/anylink

Your problem is not the return statement, but the fact that both of your conditions are true with a different URL. Why don't you negate your condition?

```
if (req.url.startsWith('/maxim/public')) {
  req = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
     }
   });
}
if (req.url.startsWith('122.22.332.3/')) {
  console.log("x");
  req = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
       Authorization: `Bearer dsfdsfdsfdsfsdxcsdfw23dsfdsf`
     }
   });
   return next.handle(req);
   }
}
```

Comment: In the components which use both api's both if's will be true. Wouldn't it work in that case, cant we set multiple auth bearer headers

Comment: Then I don't understand. You can't set the same header twice.